# Removing duplicates using several conditions using SAS

Tags: sas

[Date set having id and date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXRTe.jpg) .I want a date set with two duplicate id but condition is that one should be before 8th June and other should be after 8th June.

Comment: Please type your example data as text instead of posting a photograph of text.  Which observation do you want to keep?  Any of them?  The one with the min date? max date? Closest to june 8th?   June 8th of which year?

Comment: I want to keep two ids for each with date>8june and <8june

Comment: Show your example data as text. Show your expected results from that sample data. Explain the rules clearly.  Show what you tried and explain how it was not what you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

To take the first date and the first date after 2021-06-08 you can sort by ID and DATE and use LAG() to detect when you cross the date boundary.

```
data have ;
  input id date :date. ;
  format date date9.;
cards;
1 01jun2021
1 07jun2021
1 08jun2021
1 09jun2021 
;

data want;
  set have ;
  by id date;
  if first.id or ( (date<='08JUN2021'd) ne lag(date<='08JUN2021'd));
run;
```

results

```
Obs    id         date

 1      1    01JUN2021
 2      1    09JUN2021
```

Comment: If I have a one more variable say for example site and for different site the date condition is different(as site A date condition would be greater than 9june and for site B greater than 7july)

Comment: Either update your original question with that type of detail, or start a new question.  Make sure to include representative data and the expected results.